# How to find word hyperlink with OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

Am trying to fetch Hyperlinks address from word document from every paragraph using `OpenXML`.

```
public static string GetAddressFromPara(Paragraph Paras)
{
    IEnumerable<Hyperlink> hplk = Paras.Descendants<Hyperlink>();
    if (hplk != null)
    {
        foreach (Hyperlink hp in hplk)
        {
            //string address = ???????;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be

```
foreach (Hyperlink hp in hplk)
{
    hyperlinkText = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Text text in hp.Descendants<Text>())
        hyperlinkText.Append(text.InnerText);

    hyperlinkRelationshipId = hp.Id.Value;


    ExternalRelationship hyperlinkRelationship = doc
        .MainDocumentPart
        .ExternalRelationships
        .Single(c => c.Id == hyperlinkRelationshipId);

    hyperlinkUri = new StringBuilder(hyperlinkRelationship.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Getting error 'Sequence contains no matching element' on line ExternalRelationship hyperlinkRelationship = doc.....

Comment: Came across this answer searching for how to get the link URL from a hyperlink in word using openxml and C#. It's HyperlinkRelationships not ExternalRelationships. I was getting the sequence error too until I changed it. HIH